# How to visualize numerical data with upper and lower bounds?

Tags: data-visualization, descriptive-statistics, histogram

I have a dataset, containing some trees and the estimated upper and lower bounds of their ages. For example, tree #1 is 10~15 years old, and tree #2 is 13~20 years old, etc. I want to visualize the data.

I know that I can calculate the mean values of the bounds and plot a histogram. However, the plot would be more useful if the upper and lower bounds are also presented, since it shows the uncertainty of our estimations. How should I do that? Or is this even possible or reasonable?

My original thought is that the x-axis should be the ages and the y-axis should be the number of trees, which is the same as the histogram, but I'm not whether using these axes are possible or practical.

The followings are some samples from the dataset (unrelated columns are omitted):

| Tree ID | Estimated ages (year) (lower bound) | Estimated ages (year) (upper bound) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 15 |
| 2 | 13 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 7 | 16 |
| 5 | 13 | 15 |
| 6 | 12 | 18 |

Comment: Have you thought of boxplots?

Comment: More detail needed. Suppose one tree is 12-16 years old and another 10-18 years old, so the interval midpoint is the same. Do those trees count as the same or different? You say you want to show the uncertainty on the graph too, but  it's hard to know how to combine that with what you specify as axes. How many trees do you have, as that makes a difference to what is practical?

Comment: @Pitouille Would you mind elaborate more on how to use boxplots here? My understanding of the scenarios for boxplots is that each data has a specific value (e.g. tree #1 is 15 years old), but the scenario here is that each data has a range (e.g. tree #1 is somewhere between 10 and 15 years old.)

Comment: As @NickCox mentioned, we need to know more about your data... I think I misread your question thinking that trees belong to a category and then visualize them through boxplot... but it is actually different...

Comment: @NickCox I would say since they are different trees with different ranges, they should be consider different. Suppose that the axes I originally provided is unreasonable, could you recommend some other methods? I'll edit the question to mention this.

Comment: @Pitouille Thanks for your advice. I've edited the question to elaborate more and also attached some samples. Hope this helps.

Comment: What you show is one sample to statistical people and several samples to a biologist.... (A small deal, but watch out.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could plot each tree's interval but sort on interval midpoint at least. The "data" here are fake; I didn't have any sight of your data when I did this.

This is in effect a quantile plot with added information on uncertainty. Adding points at the midpoints and/or connecting them with a line would emphasize the overall distribution more.

Many other variations are possible. For example, if age in the data is always positive, then a transformed scale might help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Following @Nick Cox's answer (and comments - EDIT), some examples in R:

```
tree <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), c(10,13,1,7,13,12), c(15,20,3,16,15,18))

names(tree)[1]<-"TreeID"
names(tree)[2]<-"Lower"
names(tree)[3]<-"Upper"

tree <- cbind(tree, (tree$Lower + tree$Upper)/2)
names(tree)[4]<-"Avg"
tree <- cbind(tree[order(tree$Avg),], 1:6)
names(tree)[5]<-"Order"

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(tree, aes(x=Order, y=Avg)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=Lower, ymax=Upper), color="#07bbc1") +
  labs(x="Order", y = "Age in years")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(tree, aes(x=Order, y=Lower)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Order, yend = Upper), color="#07bbc1") +
  geom_point(color="#07bbc1") +
  geom_point(aes(y = Upper), color="#07bbc1")+
  labs(x="Order", y = "Age in years")
```

[image]

Comment: It is best to avoid using identifier as an axis unless that has a meaning. It's evident that the OP is interested in the frequency or probability distribution.

Comment: @NickCox, I included your comments. Thanks!